# Search specific element in list from user input

Tags: c#

I have a list that contains elements. The user should be able to search for specific element and the list. Then list should print out all lines that contains this specific element. Why is this not working?

```
 Car search = new Car();
 public void SearchLog()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
        {

            if (myList[i].Model== search.Model)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Model :" + search.Model)

            }
        }
    }
Console.Write("Search for model:");
search.searchModel = Console.ReadLine();
```

It's working now! Always something new to learn. The issue was my class variable. So I used variable from same scope instead.

Comment: Please share the code for you Car class

Comment: Yes, we need to see your code. Where is `myList` declared? Where is `search.Model` populated?

Comment: I suspect error is caused at this location, use `Console.WriteLine("Model : {0}",  search.Model);`

Comment: `search.searchModel = Console.ReadLine();` is probably the cause of your compilation error.

Comment: A more complete example would also help, this code is missing the definition of Car (is Model a string or something else), plus the last line probably is wrong on the LHS side of the assignment.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: To "search" (or "query", consider using LINQ:

    myList.Where(x => x.Model == searchModel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have complete code for you based on the information from the question and comments:

This will be the sample class for Car;

```
class Car
    {
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        //Rest of properties here
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string output = String.Format("Model :{0} \n Name :{1} \n Brand :{2}", this.Model, this.Name, this.Brand);
            return output;
        }
    }
```

Here is the main function that do the operations:

```
public static List<Car> myList = new List<Car>();
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            myList.Add(new Car() { Model = "A", Name = "XXX", Brand = "Some Brand" });
            myList.Add(new Car() { Model = "B", Name = "YYY", Brand = "Some Brand1" });
            myList.Add(new Car() { Model = "C", Name = "ZZZ", Brand = "Some Brand2" });
            Car search = new Car();
            Console.Write("Search for model:");
            search.Model = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Following Result Found for {0}", search.Model);
            SearchLog(search);
       }
```

Finally the signature for `SearchLog` is:

```
public static void SearchLog(Car search)
        {
            var resultList = myList.Where(x => x.Model == search.Model).ToList();
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var car in resultList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Result {0} : {1}", i++, myList[i].ToString());
            }
        }
```

I have another suggestion; The search need not be an object of the class `Car` It can be a string instead;

You can try it in your own way like the following:

```
 Console.Write("Search for model:");
 string inputSearch = Console.ReadLine();
 bool carFound = false;
 for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
   {
     if (myList[i].Model == inputSearch)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Model: " + myList[i].Model);
           carFound = true;
        }
   }
  if (!carFound) { Console.WriteLine("None model were found"); }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! That was great information. I've been trying to escape this code but I dont know how, tried with boolean but can't get it to work.
 for (int i = 0; i < carList.Count; i++)  { if (carList[i].Model== inputSearch) {  Console.WriteLine("Model: " + carList[i].Model)} else (Console.WriteLine("None model were found")}}

Now it declares each line a "none model were found" - this should only be a final one. Tried with bool false/true, but does not work. Any Idea?

Comment: Very useful information. 
Regarding boolean, I was almost doing the same, but couldn't get the last part. Thanks again!